# How to set delegate of modal child view controller to parent?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have everything set up correctly regarding protocol delegation etc. My only problem is that I can't set CCC's delegate to AAA. This code is in AAA.swift:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "AAAtoBBBSegue"{

                let destination = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
                let nextViewController = destination.viewControllers[0] as! CCC

                nextViewController.delegate = self

            }
        }
```

Setting the CCC delegate to AAA is my only issue! It's very frustrating because I have to set its delegate before I can pass any data from CCC to AAA.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4GNt.png

Comment: So, why can't you set the delegate?

Comment: In your screen-cap, CCC is *not* destination.viewControllers[0] .. you need to set the delegate in BBB and "pass it on" to CCC

Comment: I just put up a picture. I think it doesn't work because of BBB in between them.

Comment: Ok so, Don Mag would I set l BBB.delegate = self and then inside of BBB set CCC.delegate = self?

Comment: Almost... `BBB.delegate = self` in this prepare for segue... then, when you are segue-ing *from* BBB to CCC, you would: `CCC.delegate = self.delegate`

Comment: assuming, that is, that you really want to "reach back" to AAA from CCC

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much -- a lot simpler than I was expecting. I just have to remember: if there is a child between them, pass the delegate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer for reference...

Answer (score 0):

In your design, you are trying to set the delegate of the *second* view controller in the modally-displayed navigation controller.

You want to "pass yourself through" to reach the proper VC.

So:

- Add a delegate variable in **BBB**
- In prepare for segue from **AAA** to **BBB**, set `BBB.delegate = self` (self being **AAA**)
- In **BBB**, when you segue to **CCC**, set `CCC.delegate = self.delegate` (self here being **BBB**, and `self.delegate` is **AAA**)